React/Strapi Blog Single - JSON parse issue
Been working with React the last few days and hit a wall with this strange issue.
Im getting an API response from strapi with this json:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "documentId": "dgh7o1ezuvkxhyohh4aqwoz0",
      "title": "A bug is becoming a meme on the internet",
      "description": "How a bug on MySQL is becoming a meme on the internet",
      "slug": "a-bug-is-becoming-a-meme-on-the-internet",
      "createdAt": "2024-11-01T21:27:48.159Z",
      "updatedAt": "2024-11-02T05:01:28.536Z",
      "publishedAt": "2024-11-02T05:01:28.544Z",
      "cover": {
        "id": 7,
        "documentId": "azwnhgsu2cxw7iq3r3rrcyhq",
        "name": "a-bug-is-becoming-a-meme-on-the-internet",
        "alternativeText": "An image uploaded to Strapi called a-bug-is-becoming-a-meme-on-the-internet",
        "caption": "a-bug-is-becoming-a-meme-on-the-internet",
        "width": 3628,
        "height": 2419,
        "formats": {
          "thumbnail": {
            "name": "thumbnail_a-bug-is-becoming-a-meme-on-the-internet",
            "hash": "thumbnail_a_bug_is_becoming_a_meme_on_the_internet_a4e514880a",
            "ext": ".jpeg",
            "mime": "image/jpeg",
            "path": null,
            "width": 234,
            "height": 156,
            "size": 6.73,
            "sizeInBytes": 6728,
            "url": "/uploads/thumbnail_a_bug_is_becoming_a_meme_on_the_internet_a4e514880a.jpeg"
          },
          "large": {
            "name": "large_a-bug-is-becoming-a-meme-on-the-internet",
            "hash": "large_a_bug_is_becoming_a_meme_on_the_internet_a4e514880a",
            "ext": ".jpeg",
            "mime": "image/jpeg",
            "path": null,
            "width": 1000,
            "height": 666,
            "size": 50.97,
            "sizeInBytes": 50972,
            "url": "/uploads/large_a_bug_is_becoming_a_meme_on_the_internet_a4e514880a.jpeg"
          },
          "small": {
            "name": "small_a-bug-is-becoming-a-meme-on-the-internet",
            "hash": "small_a_bug_is_becoming_a_meme_on_the_internet_a4e514880a",
            "ext": ".jpeg",
            "mime": "image/jpeg",
            "path": null,
            "width": 500,
            "height": 333,
            "size": 19.25,
            "sizeInBytes": 19245,
            "url": "/uploads/small_a_bug_is_becoming_a_meme_on_the_internet_a4e514880a.jpeg"
          },
          "medium": {
            "name": "medium_a-bug-is-becoming-a-meme-on-the-internet",
            "hash": "medium_a_bug_is_becoming_a_meme_on_the_internet_a4e514880a",
            "ext": ".jpeg",
            "mime": "image/jpeg",
            "path": null,
            "width": 750,
            "height": 500,
            "size": 33.59,
            "sizeInBytes": 33590,
            "url": "/uploads/medium_a_bug_is_becoming_a_meme_on_the_internet_a4e514880a.jpeg"
          }
        },
        "hash": "a_bug_is_becoming_a_meme_on_the_internet_a4e514880a",
        "ext": ".jpeg",
        "mime": "image/jpeg",
        "size": 234.02,
        "url": "/uploads/a_bug_is_becoming_a_meme_on_the_internet_a4e514880a.jpeg",
        "previewUrl": null,
        "provider": "local",
        "provider_metadata": null,
        "createdAt": "2024-11-01T21:27:48.152Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-11-01T21:27:48.152Z",
        "publishedAt": "2024-11-01T21:27:48.152Z"
      },
      "author": {
        "id": 2,
        "documentId": "pubr4enhdzvyl3vj2yuytpk9",
        "name": "Sarah Baker",
        "email": "sarahbaker@strapi.io",
        "createdAt": "2024-11-01T21:27:47.017Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-11-01T21:27:47.017Z",
        "publishedAt": "2024-11-01T21:27:47.016Z"
      },
      "category": {
        "id": 2,
        "documentId": "y2wlp48gu6lcxi72nx27u5nu",
        "name": "tech",
        "slug": "tech",
        "description": null,
        "createdAt": "2024-11-01T21:27:46.584Z",
        "updatedAt": "2024-11-01T21:27:46.584Z",
        "publishedAt": "2024-11-01T21:27:46.583Z"
      },
      "blocks": [
        {
          "__component": "shared.rich-text",
          "id": 12,
          "body": "## Probant \n\nse Lorem markdownum negat. Argo *saxa* videnda cornuaque hunc qui tanta spes teneas! Obliquis est dicenti est salutat ille tamen iuvenum nostrae dolore. - Colores nocituraque comitata eripiunt - Addit quodcunque solum cui et dextram illis - Nulli meus nec extemplo ille ferebat pressit Se blandita fulvae vox gravem Pittheus cesserunt sanguine herbis tu comitum tenuit. Sui in ruunt; Doridaque maculosae fuissem! Et loqui. \n\n## Abit sua\n\nse Lorem markdownum negat. Argo *saxa* videnda cornuaque hunc qui tanta spes teneas! Obliquis est dicenti est salutat ille tamen iuvenum nostrae dolore. - Colores nocituraque comitata eripiunt - Addit quodcunque solum cui et dextram illis - Nulli meus nec extemplo ille ferebat pressit Se blandita fulvae vox gravem Pittheus cesserunt sanguine herbis tu comitum tenuit. Sui in ruunt; Doridaque maculosae fuissem! Et loqui. "
        },
        {
          "__component": "shared.quote",
          "id": 7,
          "title": "Thelonius Monk",
          "body": "You've got to dig it to dig it, you dig?"
        },
        {
          "__component": "shared.media",
          "id": 7
        },
        {
          "__component": "shared.rich-text",
          "id": 13,
          "body": "## Spatiantia astra \n\nFoeda, medio silva *errandum*: onus formam munere. Mutata bibulis est auxiliare arces etiamnunc verbis virgineo Priamidas illa Thescelus, nam fit locis lucis auras. Exitus hospes gratulor ut pondere [speslimite](http://www.curas.io/figuram); quid habent, Avernales faciente de. Pervenit Ino sonabile supplex cognoscenti vires, Bacchumque errat miserarum venandi dignabere dedisti. Discrimina iuncosaque virgaque tot sine superest [fissus](http://quos.org/sitet.aspx). Non color esset potest non sumit, sed vix arserat. Nisi immo silva tantum pectusque quos pennis quisquam artus!"
        },
        {
          "__component": "shared.slider",
          "id": 6
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "pageSize": 25,
      "pageCount": 1,
      "total": 1
    }
  }
}

All im trying to do is echo some values.
My react file here:
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const BlogPost = () => {
    const {slug} = useParams();
    
    const [post, setPost] = useState([]);
    const fetchPostLink = 'http://localhost:1337/api/articles?populate=*&filters[slug][$eq]=' + slug;
    console.log(fetchPostLink);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(fetchPostLink)
            .then((response)=>{
                setPost(response.data.data[0]);
                console.log(response.data.data[0]);
            })
            .catch((error)=>{
                console.error('Error fetching projects', error);
            })
    }, []);

    return (
        <div id="blog-single" className="blog-single">
                <div className="post-thumbnail">
                    <img src="" />
                </div>
                <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                <span>{post.author.name}</span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default BlogPost;

post.title works fine.
post.cover.url doesnt
post.author.name doesnt
Anything past the first level of json doesn't work at all, and ChatGPT isnt helping at all. What stupid mistake am I making?
Thanks everyone.
UPDATED EDIT: Quickly figured this out after posting, but leaving up for new React devs that don't understand this at first. Simple solution.
post.cover.url wont work because on page load there is no "cover" values so it throws an error. It must be checked where it is displayed. Then it wont throw an error and once the setPosts function runs, the json properly populates the "post" object. Use post.cover?.url or post.cover?.formats.thumbnail.url. This checks "cover" or "author" or any top level json keys for values before it dives to the next level.
